# Copying an image, loses Exif data

Tags: android, image, exif

I am copying an image to a private directory like so:

```
FileChannel source = null;
FileChannel destination = null;
source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
source.close();
destination.close();
```

..but when I insert it back in to Gallery, untouched, at a later time:

```
private void moveImageToGallery(Uri inUri) throws Exception {
    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), ImageUtil.loadFullBitmap(inUri.getPath()), null, null);
}
```

..it apparently loses its Exif data. The rotation no longer works. Is there some way I can copy an image file and not lose that data? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Purusing through the Google Android group leads me to believe this is an OS issue, one dev said, "seems like a valid feature request".

Comment: That's tough that there isn't a good way to do that.  What you can do is after copying the file, and before inserting it, use the ExifInterface to add the attributes that you can read from the image database such as rotation, lat/long, and date taken.  Then when you insert the image, it should read those correctly and add them to the new database entry.  Wow, just realized this is 2 years old!  I'm sure you've already done something like this, but will leave my answer here.  Not sure why this was at the top of the Android question list.

Answer (score 2):

FileChannel, here, seems to actually read the data, decode it, reencode it, then write it; thus losing the EXIF data. Copying a file (byte-by-byte) does not alter its content. The only thing that can happen before/after a copy is a file access change (remember: Android is based on Linux, Linux being an UNIX => rwx permissions (see [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod))), eventually denying the read or write of the file. So it is clear FileChannel does something unwanted.

This code will do the work:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(source);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; int len;
while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0)
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
in.close();
out.close();
```

Comment: I will give that a try. I assumed that you had to go through Android's "channel" when manipulating photos from the gallery but it is looking like that is not the case, it's just a free-for-all.